# Import data from workbooks and change the range

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I would like to copy data from one workbook and paste into the next available column of the active workbook.

I have been able to import the data from one workbook and paste it into the active sheet at a specified cell.

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim Openbook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *csv*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Openbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B145").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Openbook.Close False
    End If
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

How do I change the range from B3 to the next available column, so it will begin on B3 then C3 then D3 etc., after every workbook I select?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the literal "B2:B145" use a range specified by cells, e.g.

```
Range(Cells(2,i),Cells(145,i))
```

where i iterates over the columsn you need.

Same in the target:

```
Range(Cells(j,k))
```

where j is ruwnumber and k column of target first cell.

Comment: Sorry I am new to VBA and have limited knowledge on the topic.
Is there a change I can make to to the Range("B3") part of the code that will paste the first set of data from B2:B145 into cell B3 then the next will be C3 etc?

Comment: Implicit `ActiveSheet` is bad practice and leads to difficult-to-debug errors. See [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/8769365)

Comment: Use good practices. Use ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook - most of the time they are identical, but now always! Use with/end with to avoid long objects.

Comment: @YeOldHinnerk Thanks for the tips! I still have a question regarding the Range(Cells(j,k)) section? how can this be used to paste the in the next available column? for example paste B2:B145 from one workbook into a new workbook cells B3 then C3 etc

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public `Range` in a module:

```
Public CurrentRange As Range
```

Inside your `ImportData()` subroutine, you need to initialize it to the starting range:

```
If CurrentRange Is Nothing Then CurrentRange = [b3]
```

After you have used it, move it along to the next range:

```
Openbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B145").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).CurrentRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Openbook.Close False   
CurrentRange = CurrentRange.Offset(0,1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim Openbook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer                    '<~~~ Add integer for next range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   '<~~~ Add for any pop up screen

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *csv*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        
        For i = 2 To 4              '<~~~ 2=B 3=C 4=D and so on
        
        Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Openbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B145").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(3, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '<~~~ range change to cell
    

         Openbook.Close False
         
        Next i                      '<~~~ next after B then C then D...
    End If

    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True    '<~~~ Add for any pop up screen

End Sub
```